# Как вывести лексикографически первое (max) в словаре по ключу?

Tags: python, max, словарь

```py
r= {'ww': 1, 'j': 2, 'k': 5, 'a': 4, 'ffff': 3, 'd': 5}

r = tuple(r.items())

r_max=max(r,key=lambda x:(x[0],x[0]))

print(r_max) : ww : 1.
```

Здравствуйте!
Нужна помощь. Необходимо вывести лексикографически первое (max по ключу). Нужен ответ 'a': 4

Comment: Лексикографическое первое этот минимум.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r= {'ww': 1, 'j': 2, 'k': 5, 'a': 4, 'ffff': 3, 'd': 5}
print(list(sorted(r.items()))[0])
```

Результат:

```
('a', 4)
```

Или так:

```
r= {'ww': 1, 'j': 2, 'k': 5, 'a': 4, 'ffff': 3, 'd': 5}
print (min(r),r[min(r)])
```

Результат:

```
a 4
```